# Boson: Track anything, anywhere!

Tags: app

Boson is a both a framework to create any general purpose tracking robots for Stack Exchange 
and also a tracking bot built on top of the framework to report any content that matches a 
given set of filters, in the described way and place.

#### Example Usage

- Tracking all the new questions posted on Stack Overflow every 3 minutes (180 seconds)

  ```
  @Boson track stackoverflow questions 180
  ```
- Tracking comments every 500 seconds on PostId 93696 on the workplace

  ```
  @Boson track workplace comments 500 -f POST_ID -v 93696
  ```
- Tracking recently created tags on interpersonal skills every 6 hours and post them in a room 54445.

  ```
  @Boson track interpersonal.stackexchange.com tags 21600 -r 54445 --host STACK_EXCHANGE
  ```

#### Source Code

The source code is present [on Github](https://github.com/sobotics/boson). Check this out for a list of [commands](https://github.com/SOBotics/Boson/blob/master/docs/commands.md). The bot is currently being [built in the workshop](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167908/sobotics-workshop).